# Visual Studio Code Django project Error 404 Not Found

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

My project is named Travello, following this here:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tt3mgy2ECug&list=PLsyeobzWxl7r2ukVgTqIQcl-1T0C2mzau&index=12)`
, 
 
 When I runserver I get this error. Anybody have any clue how to fix this error:

> [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 22122
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1731
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /static/images/destination_2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1698
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /static/images/destination_5.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1698
>   Not Found: /images/intro.png
>   Not Found: /images/travello.jpg
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /images/intro.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2149
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /images/travello.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2158
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1740
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /static/styles/bootstrap4/popper.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1719
>   Not Found: /images/testimonials.jpg
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /static/images/footer_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1683
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /images/testimonials.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2170
>   Not Found: /images/home_slider.jpg
>   [16/Apr/2020 20:27:21] "GET /images/home_slider.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2167

My `settings.py` file looks like this:

```
"""
Django settings for telusko project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'telusko.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'telusko.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILS_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

and my `urls.py` in my travello folder is:

```
from django.urls import path 

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index")

]
```

This is what I'm getting chrome console when I run server:

> 127.0.0.1/:11 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>       DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map
>       DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js.map
>       DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/bootstrap4/popper.js.map
>       (index):268 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/destination_2.jpg 404 (Not
>   Found)
>       (index):304 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/destination_5.jpg 404 (Not
>   Found)
>       2
>       (index):576 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/intro.png 404 (Not Found)
>       DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map
>       testimonials.jpg:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/testimonials.jpg 404 (Not Found)
>       :8000/static/images/footer_1.jpg:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/footer_1.jpg 404 (Not Found)
>       jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/home_slider.jpg 404 (Not Found)

​

I'm new to this so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) What does this have to do with vs code?
2) Your STATICFILS_DIRS is not configured correctly.

```
STATICFILS_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/Users/username/Desktop/Telusko/Projects/telusko/static')
]
```

Use

```
STATICFILS_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static" )
]
```

This will look in folder called static that lives at the same level as your manage.py (BASE_DIR). You don't have to use this at all though if you keep a static folder in each app.

Also, just a heads up the tutorial is using django 2 and you're using django 3 which may or may not cause you problems (I haven't used 3 yet).

Comment: @sin_tribu I tried the above and it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple really. In the error page you showed, there are two types of errors.
The first looks like this.

```
27.0.0.1/:11 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map
```

You can ignore these ones.

The second sort however,

```
(index):268 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/destination_2.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Is the cause of the error. This is because while you modified the style and css files, you skipped modifying the background .jpg files in the form

```
{% static '............' %}
```

How to resolve it: Go to your index file, and search manually for the blocks of code that describes the background of the webpage. modify them as i have described below

```
style="background-image:url(images/intro.png)"></div>
```

into

```
style="background-image:url({% static 'images/intro.png' %})"></div>
```

This should work for you! and Upvote it if it does.